# Inhabilitar un boton

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Buenas tardes, estuve tratando y no entiendo como realizarlo.
Quiero que el usuario elija una opción, apretando un botón,  según el botón que haya elegido pasa determinada acción.
El problema es que si aprieta el botón A quiero que se inhabilite el botón B y viceversa
No logro hacerlo. Alguien me puede tirar una idea de como hacerlo?
Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para deshabilitar un boton se realiza mediante la propiedad `android:enabled` donde el valor boolean determina si la vista esta habilitada o deshabilitada:

El default de la vista es `android:enabled="true"` por lo cual la vista esta habilitada:

```
<Button
    android:text="Boton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:enabled="true"/>
```

programaticamente se puede realizar mediante:

```
Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
boton.setEnabled(true);  //Asigna valor true.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Inhabilitar boton:

Para **deshabilitar** un boton se realiza mediante la propiedad `android:enabled="false"`

```
<Button
    android:text="Boton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:enabled="true"/>
```

programaticamente se puede realizar mediante:

```
Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
boton.setEnabled(false); //Asigna valor false.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En el caso que comentas agrega dos botones en tu layout:

y mediante un `onClickListener` cambia habilita/deshabilita el botón:

```
    final Button botonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
    final Button botonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
    botonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            botonB.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    botonB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            botonA.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Para lo que necesitas que es elegir un botón y deshabilitar los demás considero que sería mejor usar un [RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) conteniendo varios `RadioButton` en donde al seleccionar únicamente una elemento estaría habilitado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

interesante tu pregunta, puedes probar con este codigo:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

Cuando se desea habilitar el mismo botón acaba de escribir

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setEnabled(true);
```

Sabiendo eso, creo que solo es jugar con el **If** y el **else** entre los dos botones.

Espero haberte ayudado!

> @nickoelton

Comment: Gracias, eso necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

¿Algo así?

```
mButtonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mButtonB.setEnabled(false);
    }
});


mButtonB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mButtonA.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Visualmente te recomendaría usar un CheckButton https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary#checkbox
https://github.com/rey5137/material

Comment: Gracias, eso necesitaba